# Change pointer style for <a> without href value

Tags: html, css

The page linked [here](https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/address-collection-service/) contains a row of 3 images that display text on mouse-over. I want to stick to the way I did it with  without specifying a value to href attribute because I don't want the tiles linked anywhere. I just want some text to show when cursor moves over the image. I'm looking for help to

1. To stop the image from sending the user to top of the page when the hover-over text is clicked. Or make the hover-over unclickable.
2. Changed pointer style to normal arrow style when mouse moves over the image.

Here is the code written for this particular section:

```
<!-- START SEAMLESS GIFTING FOR EVERY OCCASION -->
<?php if( have_rows('seamless_gifting') ): while( have_rows('seamless_gifting') ): the_row(); 
$title_text = get_sub_field('title_-_text');
?>
<div class="seamless-gifting front-page-row" id="row2">
  <div class="wrap-x">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="row seamless-gifting-title"><?php echo $title_text; ?></div>
      <div class="row compact">
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'occasion_column' ) ) : while ( have_rows( 'occasion_column' ) ) : the_row(); 
        $image = get_sub_field( 'gift_-_image' );
        $title_text = get_sub_field( 'title_-_text' );
        $hover_text = get_sub_field( 'hover_-_text' );
        ?>

        <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <a href="#" class="block h-100 bg-white-base transition" target="" title="">
            <div class="relative image">
              <?php if($hover_text): ?>
              <div class="textarea relative pt pb pl pr no-touch select-none">
                <div class="bg-white-base pl pr">
                  <article class="center-xs"><?php echo $hover_text; ?></article>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <?php if($image): ?>
              <div class="object-cover-wrap">
                <picture>
                  <source media="(max-width: 360px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['xsmall']); ?>">
                  <source media="(max-width: 640px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['small']); ?>">
                  <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['medium']); ?>">
                  <source srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['large']); ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo($image['sizes']['large']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                </picture>
              </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="pt pb pl pr center-xs title transition">
            <h3 class="mb0 h5 transition">
              <?php echo $title_text; ?>
            </h3>
          </div>
            </a>
                  </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<!-- END SEAMLESS GIFTING FOR EVERY OCCASION -->
```

Below is the image of the section I'm talking about.
[image]

Comment: Apply `pointer-events: none`and `cursor: default` to the `<a>`-element

Comment: With this applied, hover-over effect disappeared and the titles below the image displaced. Could you please testing it on the webpage and see if you can make it work there.?

Comment: Remove `href="#"` and the point will also change back to normal.

Comment: I didn't take the hover-effect into consideration, so that makes sense. Isn't it possible for you to just change the `<a>`-element into something else, like a `<div>`? Making it semantically correct in the first place is probably your go-to.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti, thanks. I made some progress and I now just need CSS to change the pointer to the default one. The CSS you provided in the comment above doesn't seem to work. Kindly visit the page and see if you can fix it there.

Comment: You've applied this in your CSS: `a { cursor: pointer!important; }`, remove and/or overwrite that with `cursor: default;` @PramodGangadar

Comment: @SigurdMazanti, yes, it is working now, thanks a lot. A last request for help. Could you please help center-align the titles below those images such as EMPLOYEE ENGAGEMENT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this:

```
<a href="#" class="block h-100 bg-white-base transition" target="" title="">
```

Change to this (remove `href="#"` and add `tabIndex="0"`):

```
<a tabIndex="0" class="block h-100 bg-white-base transition">
```

What `href="#"` does is, it changes the URl by appending `#` at the end of the url and that causes the browser to react and in your case it forces a page scroll to the top.

After you remove `href`, the `<a>` element will now act like an ordinary inline element like span without keyboard tab capabilities. So you must proceed to add `tabIndex="0"` to make it tab-able in the case your viewer uses a keyboad.

Comment: Thanks Mosia, can you share the CSS to change the pointer to normal arrow pointer?

Comment: @PramodGangadar Don't worry about changing pointer to normal. `href="#"` is the one that caused the pointer to change. So by removing it, the cursor will go back to default.

Comment: A last request for help. Could you please help center-align the titles below those images such as EMPLOYEE ENGAGEMENT? https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/address-collection-service/

Comment: @PramodGangadar I just checked your website. it seems like you have fixed it?

Comment: Hi Mosia, yes, I could fix it. I've been trying for days to add <h1> tag in a template that renders Author pages of a site that uses Divy theme builder. Could you please help me with that? let's connect over Skype. I see that you're from South Africa where I lived in in 2014/15 and I'm happy to have met you online. I'm from India.

Comment: Kindly mail me at pramodraam@gmail.com

Comment: I posted a new question on the same issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361874/divi-themes-template-file-appears-too-difficult-to-understand-in-terms-of-how-p